# Normalize data wih normalizr

Tags: reactjs, redux, normalizr

I need to normalize the response of the server, to save this in the redux state. The server response one array like this:

```
[  
   {  
      "name":"parches",
      "id":1,
      "numberOfbundles":0,
      "subdirectories":[  
         {  
            "name":"satelite",
            "id":2,
            "numberOfbundles":3,
            "subdirectories":[]
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "name":"layout",
      "id":3,
      "numberOfbundles":0,
      "subdirectories":[  
         {  
            "name":"clientes",
            "id":4,
            "numberOfbundles":3,
            "subdirectories":[  
               {  
                  "name":"demo",
                  "id":5,
                  "numberOfbundles":3,
                  "subdirectories":[]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I need to obtain a normalize data like this, to save it into the state:

```
{  
   "entities":{  
      "directories":{  
         "1":{  
            "name":"parches",
            "id":1,
            "numberOfbundles":0,
            "subdirectories":[  
               {  }
            ]
         },
         "2":{  
            "name":"satelite",
            "id":2,
            "numberOfbundles":3,
            "subdirectories":[  ]
         },
         "3":{  
            "name":"layout",
            "id":3,
            "numberOfbundles":0,
            "subdirectories":[  
               {  }
            ]
         },
         "4":{  
            "name":"clientes",
            "id":4,
            "numberOfbundles":3,
            "subdirectories":[  
               {  }
            ]
         },
         "5":{  
            "name":"demo",
            "id":5,
            "numberOfbundles":3,
            "subdirectories":[  ]
         }
      },
   },
   "result":[  
      1,
      2,
      3,
      4,
      5
   ]
}
```

All the directories and subdirectories must be within the object entities/directories, and the ids od the directories must be within the result array.
How I can do this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
const directory = new schema.Entity('directories')
directory.define({ subdirectories: [directory] })

normalize(data, [directory])
```

You might use `define` for creating circular references in schema.

Comment: It is not working because return null result array and the entities object is not correct.

Comment: I just tested, entities object should be correct, the results array however is what your expect. Result array only include top level result id.

Comment: If you need all directories id information, you can get it by looking up the entities directories keys.